# SwitchCompat draws additional lines

Tags: android, android-studio

Yesterday I had switched to Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 and I noticed that there were some additional lines around alls SwitchCompat views and they look deformated.

Its style just contains width/height params and vertical center, that's all. Appcompat library version is 23.4.0.

[image: Lines]

Comment: I reported the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211051&thanks=211051&ts=1464106051) as I didn't find any bug report

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found source of problem - it is android gradle plugin, go to root build.gradle file and replace 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'`

with

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`

and SwitchCompat will work as before even with 23.4.0 support library version.

Comment: Good catch, solved the problem, good workaround while waiting for the fix

Comment: You're right, this workaround works. Yesterday I noticed that the bug was random - in some builds SwitchCompat views were ok even with the Gradle Alpha version.

Comment: Thanks's man. In deed, switching back to version 2.1.0 of Android's plugin has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use library :

1- http://www.materialdoc.com/switch/

[image]

[image]

2 -https://github.com/yongjhih/SwitchPreferenceCompat

3 -https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary

4 -https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: The first one library is the one that I've bee using and I got the problem with that. The other ones aren't too useful (the last's deprecated), but thanks.